# php artisan make:migration not creaing new table

Tags: php, laravel, migration, laravel-artisan

I have a table in my db named affilaite.
But when i try to create a new table named as product it gives me an error
php artisan make:migration create_product_table

```
PHP Fatal error:  Cannot declare class CreateAffiliateTable, because the name is already in use in /home/manak/Desktop/manu/Edolve/database/migrations/2021_03_09_063908_create_affiliate_table.php on line 7

   Symfony\Component\ErrorHandler\Error\FatalError 

  Cannot declare class CreateAffiliateTable, because the name is already in use

  at database/migrations/2021_03_09_063908_create_affiliate_table.php:7
      3▕ use Illuminate\Database\Migrations\Migration;
      4▕ use Illuminate\Database\Schema\Blueprint;
      5▕ use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Schema;
      6▕ 
  ➜   7▕ class CreateAffiliateTable extends Migration
      8▕ {
      9▕     
     10▕       Run the migrations.
     11▕      


   Whoops\Exception\ErrorException 

  Cannot declare class CreateAffiliateTable, because the name is already in use

  at database/migrations/2021_03_09_063908_create_affiliate_table.php:7
      3▕ use Illuminate\Database\Migrations\Migration;
      4▕ use Illuminate\Database\Schema\Blueprint;
      5▕ use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Schema;
      6▕ 
  ➜   7▕ class CreateAffiliateTable extends Migration
      8▕ {
      9▕     
     10▕       Run the migrations.
     11▕      

      +1 vendor frames 
  2   [internal]:0
      Whoops\Run::handleShutdown()
```

Comment: A class with that name already exists. Use another name for your migration or delete the old one first.

Comment: Have your migration already executed with this class name `CreateAffiliateTable ` ? May be you have same class name in migration. try to change the name or you can can give `CreateAffiliateV1Table `.

Answer (score 0):

From This error I Think U already have A migration named `CreateAffiliateTable`.

Please Change Your Migration name or Delete the Old migration

Answer (score 0):

Check your database/migration folder. if a file already prosent there remove it. Also if there is already a table named exactly the same drop that table from database. Also in database there is a migrations table. Delete the tablename from there also and try migrating again.
By laravel convention migrations are plural and model name singular. So better try CreateAffiliatesTable instead of CreateAffiliateTable

Answer (score 0):

use this command for create
$ php artisan make:migration create_products_table